# In Private Sub on change in specific cells, the macro which is being called, goes back to private sub without completion of macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Private sub which calls a specific macro on change in cell value. However, when it calls the macro, the macro runs party and then automatically switches to beginning of private sub without going through all the lines of the macro. Not sure why that is happening. I am not a pro in vba but have done lots of practice. So sorry if this sounds to be a stupid question. Thank you!

Regards,
Aanand

Here's the private sub:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("K2:N2")) Is Nothing Then
Call RetrieveActual
End If

End Sub
```

Here's the macro:

```
Sub RetrieveActual()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False



Sheets("Actual hours Database").Select
Range("A904857").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 7).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-7]&RC[-6]"
Selection.Copy
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Sheets("Actual hours").Select
Range("C7").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IFERROR(INDEX('Actual hours Database'!C3:C5,MATCH('Actual hours'!R5C&'Actual hours'!RC35,'Actual hours Database'!C8,0),MATCH('Actual hours'!RC2,'Actual hours Database'!R1C3:R1C5,0)),0)"
Selection.Copy

Range("C7:AG9").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Range("C11:AG13").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Range("C15:AG17").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Range("C19:AG21").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Range("C23:AG25").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Range("C27:AG29").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Range("C31:AG33").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Range("C35:AG37").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Range("C39:AG41").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Application.CutCopyMode = False

Sheets("Actual hours Database").Select
Columns("H:H").ClearContents

Sheets("Actual hours").Select
Range("A1").Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Disable events: `Application.EnableEvents = False` and then re-enable at the end.

Comment: If that ^^ didn't help, step through the code using F8 so that you can see where it stops. Include that information here.

Comment: It didn't work. It jumps back to private sub in the following line:

Comment: ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IFERROR(INDEX('Actual hours Database'!C3:C5,MATCH('Actual hours'!R5C&'Actual hours'!RC35,'Actual hours Database'!C8,0),MATCH('Actual hours'!RC2,'Actual hours Database'!R1C3:R1C5,0)),0)"

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("K2:N2")) Is Nothing Then
        Call RetrieveActual
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

**NOTE:**

As a matter of programming style for event code, I suggest:

- always beginning and ending event code with the disable/enable
- only exiting the code from the bottom

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, it does not work. It still jumps after executing the following line:

Comment: ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _ "=IFERROR(INDEX('Actual hours Database'!C3:C5,MATCH('Actual hours'!R5C&'Actual hours'!RC35,'Actual hours Database'!C8,0),MATCH('Actual hours'!RC2,'Actual hours Database'!R1C3:R1C5,0)),0)"